# Error Connecting to EPP Server Using openssl s_client

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm currently trying to connect to an EPP server using openssl s_client  to verify my connection. The below command outputs the following.

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:700
```

Response:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
41282:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL0 98-64.30.2/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL alert number 40
41282:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.30.2/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:185:
```

I then proceeded to download the DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA from https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt

I then re-attempted using a self-signed cert created with openssl, along with the new DigiCert certificate.

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:700 -CAfile DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -debug
```

And I get the same error. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `s_cient` command is probably wrong. Use TLS 1.0 (or above) and [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to connect. `openssl s_client -connect example.com:700 -tls1 -servername example.com`

Comment: I tried that using `-tls1` and `-servername example.com`. Still same response. Also tried `-ssl2` and `-ssl3` with same response. I'm guessing, from the response, that it's a certificate issue. I just have no idea how to fix the issue. I'm just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provide the client gets the certificate from the server and continues with the handshake but then gets a handshake_failure (alert 40) back from the server. Getting this error at this stage of handshake is likely caused by the server expecting to get a client certificate which the client did not provide. But, to be really sure one would need to have more information, ideally a full packet capture of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a self-signed certificate you should use the same file for both `-CAfile` and `-cert`. If you are using DigiCert CA in `-CAfile` then in `-cert` it should be a certificate signed by DigiCert.

Also the server needs to accept your certificate, which means it needs to have its CA (and possible intermediate CAs) beforehand.